# Secure boot inconsistent behavior

Tags: secure-boot

I have two systems with 20.04 LTS. Secure boot is enabled on both. The behavior of the two systems is different, and I have not idea why.

System 1: Asks for a new secure boot password on each kernel update (I assume it's new, since it asks for a re-type). Why?

System 2: Never asks for anything on kernel update. Running 'mokutil --sb-state' indicates SecureBoot is enabled.

Why the difference, and how should it act?

Comment: Does one system have a proprietary video or Wi-Fi driver? Ubuntu cannot sign proprietary drivers. So you as use have to sign the driver. Did you install driver from Ubuntu repository?

Comment: @oldfred Yes indeed it does. That explains it. I'm using proprietary AMD-Pro drivers. Is there a way to sign to enable secure boot?

Comment: I do not use proprietary drivers, not currently use UEFI Secure Boot. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS If you have Secure Boot on, I thought it asked you to assign a MOK - machine owner key. Or then you are signing that the Software blob is Secure as Ubuntu cannot verify third party software, but a user can.